# How to get win32_service recovery tab properties

Tags: windows, powershell, service, win32-process

Regarding service's recovery tab properties that can be seen here:

[image: http%253A%252F%252Fwww.ehloworld.com%252Fwp-content%252Fuploads%252F2011%252F10%252Fservice-recovery-options-1.png]

Is there an API to get the following property values:

1. First failure  for example value: "Take no action"
2. Second failure
3. Subsequent failures
4. Reset fail count

I prefer a way to do so in PowerShell but would like to know about other options as well.

Comment: Removed C# tag as this question doesn't appear to have anything specifically concerning C#.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with PowerShell, but there is a Win32 API available: [QueryServiceConfig2()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684935%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Set the `dwInfoLevel` parameter to `SERVICE_CONFIG_FAILURE_ACTIONS`, and pass a pointer to a buffer in the `lpBuffer` parameter that is large enough to receive a `SERVICE_FAILURE_ACTIONS` struct.

Answer (score 0):

One needs to modify the services reg key, under

```
HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\services\<service name>\
```

Adding a value of type `binary` with the name `FailureActions`. I don't know how it's structured you'd have to play around with that, but as it relates to powershell it would simply be grabbing to real name of the service (maybe using `get-service` if all you have is the display name), and navigating to that regkey and creating a new value, for example:

```
PS C:\Users\*\Desktop> $ByteArray = 0,0,0,144,10,23,253,33                                                                                                               
PS C:\Users\*\Desktop> Set-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\AdobeARMservice -Name FailureActions -Type Binary -Value $ByteArray -Force         
PS C:\Users\*\Desktop> Get-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\AdobeARMservice -Name FailureActions                                               


FailureActions : {0, 0, 0, 144...}                                                                                                                                           
PSPath         : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\AdobeARMservice                                                    
PSParentPath   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services                                                                    
PSChildName    : AdobeARMservice                                                                                                                                             
PSDrive        : HKLM                                                                                                                                                        
PSProvider     : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry
```

Adding a byte[ ], but like I mentioned you'd have to either reverse engineer the meaning of the array, or just copy an existing one or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can control it for instance with cs.exe

```
Get-Service -DisplayName YourService | % { sc.exe failure $_.Name actions= /0 reset= 0 }
```